# Changing speed based on player direction and angle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently when I am moving upwards on an angled surface that is greater than **30** degrees my player movement speed is decreased and then when I turn around and start moving downhill while still on that same slope which is greater than **30** degrees my player speed reverts back to default which is good.

But I am facing a problem where if I walk upwards on that slope but I am walking backwards, my player speed doesn't decrease and it remains at default. I thought I had solved this by using `Vector3.SignedAngle` to get my direction but I haven't been able to get it working.

```
if (isGrounded && Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out RaycastHit hit, 2f))
{
    float angle = Vector3.SignedAngle(hit.normal, Vector3.up, transform.right);
    float slopeAngle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, hit.normal);

    if (slopeAngle > 30f)
    {
        if (angle < 0) // if moving uphill
        {
            speed = 2f; // lower the speed
        }
        else
        {
            speed = 5f; // revert speed to default
        }
    }
    else
    {
        speed = 5f; // default speed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the dot product between the player's forward direction and the slope normal to determine whether the player is moving uphill or downhill, something like this :

```
if (isGrounded && Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out RaycastHit hit, 2f))
{
    float slopeAngle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, hit.normal);
    float slopeDirection = Vector3.Dot(transform.forward, -hit.normal);

    if (slopeAngle > 30f)
    {
        if (slopeDirection > 0) // moving uphill
        {
            speed = 2f; // lower the speed
        }
        else
        {
            speed = 5f; // revert speed to default
        }
    }
    else
    {
        speed = 5f; // default speed
    }
}
```

the dot product here is used to figure out whether the player is moving uphill (dot product > 0) or downhill (dot product < 0). This adjustment is designed to help you manage the speed based on both the slope angle and the direction of movement on the slope.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This still produces the same issue and I even tried to add an `else if` statement after the `slopeDirection > 0` but there still hasn't been any change